# input a letter, store in a variable print the letter to the command line

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, variables, user-input, windows-7-x64

I am trying to make a very basic program to compare 2 numbers.  after entering the 2 numbers the user is asked if they want to compare the 2 numbers. if y/n for yes or no. the problem I run into is that the program does not seem to ask for my input and immediately goes to the next print statement. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void){

    int n1;
    int n2;
    char ch;
    printf("compare 2 numbers, input a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    printf("your first number is %d\n", n1);
    printf("enter your second number to compare \n");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    printf("your second number is %d\n", n2);
    printf("do you want to compare these numbers? y/n \n");
    //here is the problem. after entering y, the program closes. 
    //at this point I just want it to print the letter it was given by the user.
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    //the print statement that is supposed to print the letter the user inputs
    printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

//I was using this code as a reference which runs correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;

    printf("Enter a character\n");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'I'
        || ch =='o' || ch=='O' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U')
        printf("%c is a vowel.\n", ch);
    else
        printf("%c is not a vowel.\n", ch);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
printf("enter your second number to compare \n");
scanf("%d", &n2);
```

you will enter the second number and press `ENTER`. This `ENTER (\n)` is still there in the buffer.
The `scanf` function removes whitespace automatically. `scanf()` leaves the new line char in buffer when you are using `%c` (`%c` are the exception they don't remove `whitespace`).

`scanf("%c", &ch);`

instead of this use

```
scanf("\n%c", &ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use %c,spaces and "escape character" as a valid character.So it will be stored in the ch.In the first two scanf,you use the %d can do no wrong.

In the second program,you call scanf("%c", &ch); at the first.This problem does not arise.If you call again, also can appear the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem is newline character `\n` leftover by the previous `scanf` after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This `\n` is left for the next call of `scanf`.
To avoid this problem you need to place a space before `%c` specifier in your `scanf`.

```
scanf(" %c", &C);  
...
scanf(" %c", &B);
...
scanf(" %c", &X);
```

A space before `%c` is able to eat up any number of newline characters.

OR

You can use scanf to eat the single character without assigning it to anything like this::

```
scanf( "%[^\n]%*c", &C ) ;
```

`%[^\n]` tells the scanf to read every character that is not `'\n'`. That leaves the `'\n'` character in the input buffer, then the `* (assignment suppression)` will consume the a single character `('\n')` but would not assign it to anything.